# Marginal PDF from joint PDF question

Tags: calculus, probability

[image]

I am working on the 6.041 MIT Opencourseware course. Though, currently I am struggling with assignment 1b of the attached assignment (see pic).

As the joint pdf is linear (red circle), I do not see why the marginal PDF of Y can be quadratic (orange arrow). My feeling is that the provided solution mistakenly calculates the CDF.

What I did when trying to solve this; was to create a definite integral with bounds 1 and 2. In other words, replace the y (green arrow) with a 2. Though, as a result I would then have a new problem, as with this approach I would only have a constant (no variable) in my marginal PDF.

Do I have a mistake in my understanding? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could typeset your question plus your attempts in MathJax. General hint: The marginal pdf of a joint pdf is obtained by integrating out the other variable. Here $x$.

Comment: Please format your question using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I think you misremembered what "marginal PDF" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, draw the three inequalities $$ 1 \leq x \leq y \leq 2$$ in the xy-plane. Then find their intersection.
[image]

To find the marginal PDF $f_Y(y)$, you have to integrate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ over the triangle depicted in the figure. Look at the arrow. It passes through $x=1$ first and then it passes through $x=y$. So
$$ f_Y(y)=\int_{x=1}^{x=y} \frac{3}{2}x\, dx$$
for $1\leq y \leq 2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It clicked!